# ActiveMerchant USA Epay ignore duplicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant, usaepay

Based on USAEpay docs, it's possible to set ignore_duplicate. Something related to UMignoreDuplicate.

Can someone please advice on how to use it? Or set it? I already tried below command and seems not to be working...

```
>     gateway= ActiveMerchant::Billing::UsaEpayTransactionGateway.new(_credentials)
>     options[:ignore_duplicate] = true
>     gateway.purchase(order_amount, credit_card, options)
```

Comment: Could you please post a link to this doc youre talking about?

Comment: https://wiki.usaepay.com/developer/transactionapi